# Need Regex to replace all characters between first set of parenthesis from a string

Tags: java, regex

I've been able to generate a regex to pull everything that is between parenthesis in a string, but I'm unclear on how to make it only happen once and only with the first set. In JAVA:

My current pattern = `"\\(([^)]+)\\)"`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://ideone.com/ek8gQV)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `replaceFirst` instead of `replaceAll`

OR if you must use `replaceAll` let it consume rest of your string and put it back again like

```
replaceAll("yourRegex(.*)","yourReplacement$1");
```

where `$1` represents match from first group `(.*)`.

Comment: @ndn I am not sure what you mean. Wouldn't this replace last occurrence of `(...)` (the one after which no `(..)` exist)? If that is what you mean then based on "how to make it only happen once and only with the *first set*" I suspect that this is not what OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
String x= "Hie(Java)";
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)").matcher(x);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

or

```
String str = "Hie(Java)";
String answer = str.substring(str.indexOf("(")+1,str.indexOf(")"));
```

for last index:
update with

```
 String answer = str.substring(str.indexOf("(")+1,str.lastIndexOf(")"));
```

Comment: OP wants to replace only first occurrence of `(...)` but your first solution only finds all `(..)` (OP already knows how to match it - `"\\(([^)]+)\\)"`) and second solution can be error prone in case of data like `) .. (` where first `)` is placed before first `(`.

Comment: Your updated code has another problem. Lets say that our input is `ab (cd) ef (gh) ij`. Subtracting from first `(` to last `)` will return `(cd) ef (gh)` which I suspect is not what OP wants (but I may be wrong). Also your code doesn't check if there is data which should be returned. For instance for data like `ab (cd` it will throw exception. Same if only `)` is placed before first `(` like `"foo) bar (baz"`. That is one of reasons why it is better to use tested build-in methods like `replaceAll` or `replaceFirst` which will handle such cases for us.

Comment: accept but i've just given the hint like OP has given only one line of code. rest of the logic depends on OP.

Comment: That is why I didn't down-vote your answer, since it can be easily adapted and corrected :) I was just pointing out possible problems which reader should consider when using your solution.